# Ejb returns java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I am newbie in cdi and these are my first steps.
I have a bean in ejb module:

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean {
    public String getIt(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

I have a POJO in war module (I tried with @EJB and @Inject - same result)

```
public class SaveAction  extends Action{
    @EJB    
    private TestBean bean;

    @Override
    public void execute(){
    ....    
    String test = bean.getIt(); //HERE I GET java.lang.NullPointerException
    ...
    }
}
```

Both war and ejb are inside ear. In log I see

> EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TestBean:
>   [java:global/example.com/my-ejb/TestBean!com.example.TestBean,
>   java:global/example.com/my-ejb/TestBean]]]

From that I conclude that bean is initialized - but I can't find it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is SaveAction instantiated / who instantiates it?

Comment: @isnot2bad It's instantiated in servlet.

Comment: so you do it via 'new'?

Comment: @PashaTurok, Probably you try to Inject EJB bean on Struts, Please try it on HTTPServlet.

Comment: @Masud We don't use Struts.

Comment: I am guessing that CDI only works to inject components into other container managed components (Servlets etc.) so it will not appear when you do a `new`

Comment: @PashaTurok when you create the bean by yourself with 'new', no magical injection will happen! Let the CDI container create your bean, then it will work!

Comment: @user2310289 How can it be true? It's common design approach that only one servlet is used. Beans are beans. But beside them a lot of pojo. And can't CDI be used there?

Comment: @isnot2bad I don't instantiate bean (i.e. I don't use new TestBean())! I use new SaveAction()

Comment: @PashaTurok I think you are confusing things.  You previously said that SaveAction was `new'd` but now I see it is an action.  I think the error is meaning that it can not find your EJB using the JNDIs ava:global/example.com/my-ejb/TestBean!com.example.TestBean, java:global/example.com/my-ejb/TestBean

Comment: @user2310289 I also think that it can't find my bean. So I wrote it my question.

Comment: But what is an `Action`? You say you do not use struts.  You say it is instaiated via `new`

Comment: @PashaTurok CDI managed beans can only be injected in other CDI managed beans. So your SaveAction must be CDI managed too to make this work!

Comment: @user2310289 (Save)Action is a POJO that in instantiated (via new) in servlet and "does some job".

Comment: @isnot2bad Are you sure? Can you answer my question with references? I mean not in comments.

Comment: Have a look at this article  http://antoniogoncalves.org/2011/01/12/bootstrapping-cdi-in-several-environments/  Try injecting the bean in the servlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDI and other dependency injection containers don't use magic! It's just ordinary java code that cannot do more or less than any other java code written anywhere. So it is impossible for a framework to do injection when an object is instantiated directly via `new`:

```
SaveAction action = new SaveAction();
// don't expect any injection has happened - it can't! no magic!
// action.bean is still null here!
```

The framework does not have any idea that an object like SaveAction has been instantiated. (Therefore it would be necessary to somehow inform the framework about the newly created object - but neither the constructor nor the 'new' statement do this! Just think one minute about how you would write such a framework code! It's not possible!* ).

To make injection work, the object must be created by the container instead! Otherwise it is NOT managed! (See also chapter 3.7 of the [Web Beans specification (JSR 299)](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr299/index.html)).

The best way to do this is to let the container inject the object into another already managed bean. It seems this just deferes the problem, but there are some already managed beans in your application, like the servlet!

Suggestion: Make your SaveAction CDI aware (e.g. annotate it with `@Default`) and let it be injected into your servlet!

Tutorials:

- http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1063
- http://hudson.jboss.org/jenkins/job/JBoss-AS7-Docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/guides/developer-getting-started-guide/target/docbook/publish/en-US/html/helloworld.html

---

*) In theory it should be possible using aspect oriented programming or instrumentation to manipulate the constructors of beans to notify the container if they are invoked. But that's a very complex concept with many unsolved issues I think.

Comment: Will he believe you now?

Comment: @isnot2bad You know, the most important part of your answer is "CDI and other dependency injection containers don't use magic!" because everything becomes clear when you start to think how it works.

Comment: @PashaTurok That's why it is in the first line! ;)